# refrescar - limpiar JtextArea -java

Tags: java, eventos

tengo una consulta:
Cual sería la forma de refrescar (que no se duplique/acumule) el texto de un JtextArea al presionar un botón? - Pues al presionar por ejemplo el botón "Ver Resultado" varias veces, la información se va agregando o duplicando en el textArea.
 - de la misma forma si lo hago de un JComboBox, al cambiar de item, me muestra informacion en el textarea pero no elimina la informacion del anterior item seleccionado o al ir alternando entre las opciones del JcomboBox. 
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Sería bueno que pongáis el código, asumo que sí se repite el texto, es porque lo estas concatenando **+=**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay un metodo que tiene cada JTextField el cual se llama setText(). con ese metodo puedes setear la informacion actual que hay en el TextField un ejemplo de ello seria:

```
JTexfield1.setText("");
```

Para que no se te acomulen los datos o los resultados tendrias que setearlos al princio de cada funcion o lo que es decir colocar el setText con comillas vacias

Comment: gracias me faltaba setearlos al inicio de la funcion, gracias.